# undefined method where for #<Array:0x007fd619b022b8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to select an element from a cached Array, but it's not working. I'm doing the following :

```
> t=Task.last
=> #<Task id: 26, title: "Soloff" created_at: "2017-12-11 13:48:17", updated_at: "2017-12-11 15:57:12"> 
> t.cached_reminds 
 => [#<TaskRemind id: 3, deleted_state: false, task_id: 26, user_id: 1, date: "2017-12-27 23:00:00", created_at: "2017-12-11 16:28:34", updated_at: "2017-12-11 16:28:34">, #<TaskRemind id: 2, deleted_state: false, task_id: 26, user_id: 1, date: "2017-12-28 23:00:00", created_at: "2017-12-11 16:27:16", updated_at: "2017-12-11 16:27:16">]
```

So my request render the good Array, but after, when I try to run :

```
t.cached_reminds.where(user_id: 1)
```

The action where is not recognized

Can you help me on it ?

EDIT :

Form my model Task :

```
def cached_reminds
  Rails.cache.fetch([self, "task_reminds"]) {task_reminds.to_a}
end
```

Oddly, when I try to run :

```
t.task_reminds.where(user_id: 1)
```

It's working !!

Comment: What's `cached_reminds`?

Comment: It's a cahe method form a model task.

Comment: Yep, I've post it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return in the block the cached `task_reminds`, without converting it to an array, this way it'd give you a `TaskRemind::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` object and you're able to use `where`. Unlike using an array, where you'd have to use something to filter the elements inside of it:

```
def cached_reminds
  Rails.cache.fetch([self, 'task_reminds']) { task_reminds }
end

last_task = Task.last.task_reminds
last_task.cached_reminds
# => => TaskRemind::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy
last_task.cached_reminds.where user_id: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `cached_reminds` seems like an Array of records, so you cannot use ActiveRecord's query method `where`

For ruby's array, you can use `select {}` for similar with AR `where`. Notice the block passed to method

```
t.cached_reminds.select { |cached| cached.user_id == 1 }
#=> An array of TaskRemind records or empty array
```

For more information, please read about [`Array#select {}`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-select) and

Comment: Cool !! Thanks for your answer @yeuem1vannam . I did not know this method. Thanks for your precious help